# Показать кнопки при наведении мыши на элемент и наоборот

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть картинки, у всех одинаковые идентификаторы (они из базы выводятся). Хотелось бы с помощью JQuery сделать так, чтоб при наведении мыши на картинке появилась кнопка редактирования и удаления, а когда уводишь кнопки исчезали.

Написал код, но картинки не видны на экране, Firebag ошибок не показывает, но код в HTML  добавляет.

Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newSS img').hover(function(){
    var a = '<img class="a" src="images/setting.png" width="16" height="16"><img class="a" src="images/btn_close.png" width="16" height="16">';
    $(this).append('<div class="aa">'+a+'</div>');
    }, function(){ $('.aa').remove(); });
});
```

Comment: На [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) выложите пример.

Comment: **у всех одинаковые идентификаторы** Думайте что делаете и что говорите. Никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах одинаковых идентификаторов не должно быть на странице. Я не представляю как вы их еще в базе o.O собрались изменять...

Comment: @Maris, человек просто не правильно выразился. )) Если бы не было кода, который он показал, где становится ясно, что под "идентификаторами", имелся в виду общий стиль, то можно было бы и побурчать ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).append('<div class="aa">'+a+'</div>');
```

- вот где проблема!

Фактические это -

```
$('#newSS img').append('<div class="aa">'+a+'</div>');
```

То есть вы вставляете div во внутрь img! вот [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/bH2VQ/) на ваш пример.

Если делать то нужно обернуть картинку например дивом, тогда ваш код будет выглядеть так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newSS div').hover(function(){
    var a = '<img class="a" src="images/setting.png" width="16" height="16"><img class="a" src="images/btn_close.png" width="16" height="16">';
    $(this).append('<div class="aa">'+a+'</div>');
    }, function(){ $(this).children('.aa').remove(); });
});
```

Вот [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/Dkhpg/) на работающий пример на jquery.
Вот [ссылка](http://jsfiddle.net/ByxRZ/1/) на работающий пример на css

Comment: А вообще проще это выдавить сразу просто код готовый со скрытыми картинками через display:none; , а через css на :hover изменять на display: block;

Comment: Андрей Советкин, да вы правы, я создавал директорию в jpg, пробовал ваш код, но опять же не сработал. 
Вы еще написали цитирую: "А вообще проще это выдавить сразу просто код готовый со скрытыми картинками через display:none; , а через css на :hover изменять на display: block;"
Может я не правильно понял или... Здесь без JQuery можно обойтись? если так было бы здорово.

Comment: Ну мой код работает - ссылка тому подтверждение, скорее вы неправильно её вставляете. А можно без jquery обойтись. Добавил ссылку на пример с чистым css.

Comment: Клево!!! Спасибо! Сработал код!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#newSS img').each(function(index) {
 this.hover(function(){
        var setting = document.createElement('img');
        setting.width=16;
        setting.height=16;
        setting.src = 'images/setting.png';
        var close = document.createElement('img');
        close.width=16;
        close.height=16;
        close.src = 'images/btn_close.png';

        var handler = document.createElement("div"); 
        div.appendChild(setting);
        div.appendChild(close);
        this.appendChild();
    },function(){ this.removeChild(handler);});

});
```

Не пинайте сильно за код с коленки, но общий принцип как-то так